# What are the permissions to enable changing of documentviewer settings in Plone for a Reader?

Tags: plone

In Plone Unified installer v.4.1.4 with collective.documentviewer 2.2.1, I wish to enable document settings tab for a custom role i.e a reader who has view access and also who can only change the 'document settings' in the folder. I wish to allow this custom_reader role  to download the file. I have disabled the at_download. My idea is the default 'Reader' role can access only documents for view, while the custom_reader role can access the document viewer settings in the submenu tab and enable 'Show sidebar' so that he can download the 'Original Document' by clicking on it. I want to know which is the exact permission(s) in the Security tab of ZMI which helps control this. At the moment if I allow edit permissions, the settings for this are editable but otherwise for the custom_reader though I allow 'Modify portal content' and 'Modify view template' the document viewer settings  when clicked for the uploaded file shows message : 'You have insufficient rights..'. I do not wish to allow any other permissions to the custom_reader role.

> I have custom workflow for folders which has only 'private' state
>   without any transitions. Each folder will have 2 users 1. reader and
>   other 2. custom_reader with download  option. The entire plone site
>   document viewer settings is set to show in full screen by default. So I want the
>   permission for the custom_reader such that he can set the
>   documentviewer settings to show the sidebox so that he can download
>   using the 'Original Document' hyperlink. While the reader should not
>   be able to download the file as he cannot access the sidebox of the
>   documentviewer.

Answer (score 1):

You're question is a little unclear but here is what is happening.

The permission required is "Modify portal content" to be able to edit those settings and "Modify view template" for the button to show up.

I think this is a mistake as it should use the same button for both. Perhaps a pull request is needed.

That being said, if you grant these permissions, it should work as you expect. You'll also need to make sure your custom_reader role has View permission of course.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/627308/vangheem giving the custom_reader role the permissions "Modify portal content" and "Modify view template" and the 'View' definitely shows the tab 'Document Viewer Settings next to 'View' tab, but on clicking  gives message 'Insufficient previleges..'. I need this desperately. Kindly guide.

Comment: I just tried it and it works. Are you certain your workflows are setup correctly and setting the permissions correctly on the object? Append /manage_access onto the url of the file you're testing to make sure the correct security settings are getting applied

Comment: I have a custom workflow for folders i.e private state without any transitions. To the files uploaded in this folder I need to give the permission for view and print role only. No other permissions should be given like edit. Can you tell me exactly how you were able to achieve this? While reader role should not be able to change the document viewer settings locally.

Comment: All I did was add a custom_reader role, append /manage_access onto a private file object which has simple publication workflow on it, and give custom_reader View, Modify portal content and Modify view template permissions. If your workflow is setup properly it should grant these permissions automatically. Maybe you need to run the update permissions button in portal_workflow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/627308/vangheem. It did not work in my case with above mentioned settings. Please note that the default global documentviewer settings for the entire site is to 'not display the sidebar'. Is the message 'Insufficient previl..' displayed due to that?